# How to seperate search results into categories like Ebay?

Tags: asp.net, search

I am trying to create a search filter much like the one used on eBay that dynamically comes up with appropriate search categories based on the search results left. For example: http://electronics.shop.ebay.com/iPod-MP3-Players-/73839/i.html?_trksid=p3910.c0.m485

As you can see the search filters on the left are based upon the details displayed on the product results.

I need to try and implement something similar for an ASP.NET site, whereby I need to filter articles based on fields such as sales, companies, employee numbers etc. My database is quite normalised so I am able to separate all the data into their own tables.

I am not too sure how I go about doing this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you would get your initial search result set (this could be a single item selected by the user) and from there retrieve a distinct list of all associated search terms. This does rely on the fact that you have generated an index of search terms from the data, this could be done through a keyword field when the record is created or using some other algorithm (using a dictionary of common words for instance).

Once you break the task into "retrieve search terms" and then "get associated unique keywords/search terms" then it's relatively simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is something I will have to try based on what you have told me. But I think since the data in my articles will vary on their type I am still a bit uncertain how I will implement the search. But I think I will see what I can do.